# Change dimmer to normal light switch

Tags: electrical

I have changed a dimmer to a normal light switch.
On dimmer there were two red cables: 1 going into L1 and the other into a wavy line with arrow through it.

I have put L1 to L1 on normal switch and wavy line to common on light switch is this correct?

Comment: What will you do about ground?

Answer (score 2):

### This is fine

Ordinary light switches don't make any distinction between "line" and "load" sides; in fact, in North America, we mark the two "live" terminals on an ordinary wall switch identically (they're both brass screws, vs. the black screw used for the common terminal on a 3-way wall switch).  So, you can connect it either way around, and it'll still work.

Comment: From a dimmer to an ordinary light switch...  that's something you don't see every day.+1